# Twig doesn't approximate number

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a strange situation. My code is :

```
{% set total_amount=0 %}
{% for result in a_result %}
   <tr>
      <td>{% set total_amount=total_amount+("%.2f"|format(result.tva*result.prix_ht)) %}
      {{ "%.2f"|format(result.tva*result.prix_ht) }}
      </td>
   /tr>
 {% endfor %}
 <tr>
     <td colspan="5">Total</td>
     <td>{{ total_amount }}</td>
 </tr>
```

As result I have : 
`15.98, 25.49, 25.49`
And `Total = 65` but total should be equal with `65.96`. I don't understand where is the problem. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Offtopic comment here. Just wanted to help on the naming convention you're doing on for loop in twig. It would be nice if you could do `{% for result in results %}` So it would be `for singular in plural` So it's nice to read. :)

Comment: Secondly, why not just do the sum in your PHP instead of twig?

Comment: As @Farkie says, please let PHP / the Controller do the work, and use Twig for the presentation. The rounding problem lies in your first line, you should make it `{% set total_amount = 0.00 %}`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the [round](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/round.html) and [number_format](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html) filter as follow:

```
{% set total_amount=0 %}
{% for result in a_result %}
{% set value = (result.tva* result.prix_ht)|round(2) %}
{% set total_amount=total_amount+value %}
   <tr>
      <td>
      {{ value|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
      </td>
   /tr>
 {% endfor %}
 <tr>
     <td colspan="5">Total</td>
     <td>{{ total_amount|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>
 </tr>
```

A running example with sample data in this [twigfiddle files](http://twigfiddle.com/twzyfb)

Hope this help